# How do i get Typed.js to work in a python Dash application?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, typed.js

I'm trying to have the Typed.js packages to work in a Dash application. With Typed.js the text and a page gets written dynamically using a certain list of words. Minimal code example:

```
import dash
from dash import html

# import grasia_dash_components as gdc
# import dash_defer_js_import as dji

external_scripts = [
    'https://unpkg.com/typed.js@2.0.15/dist/typed.umd.js',
    ]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_scripts=external_scripts)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1(["Hello, ",html.Span("Dash", className="mov", id="mov"),"!"]),
    ]
)

# app.layout.children.append(gdc.Import(src="./20_typed.js"))
app.layout.children.append(dash.html.Script("""
    var typed = new Typed("#mov", {
        strings: ["for one", "for two", "for three"],
        typeSpeed: 150,
        backSpeed: 150,
        loop: true
    });
"""))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I tried several options but to not success:

1. Via dash.html.Script
2. Via a js file in the assets folder (same javascript as in the code in the assets folder)
3. Via grasia packages (20_typed.js in root folder and same javascript as in the code code)

In the code example option 3 is commented out to show you what i did (also with dji didn't get it to work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a client side callback

```
from dash import Dash, html                                                                               
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input                                                               
                                                                                                          
app = Dash(__name__, external_scripts=["https://unpkg.com/typed.js@2.0.15/dist/typed.umd.js"])            
                                                                                                          
app.layout = html.Span(id="element")                                                                      
                                                                                                          
app.clientside_callback(                                                                                  
    """                                                                                                   
    function(input) {                                                                  
        var typed = new Typed('#element', {                                                               
          strings: ['<i>First</i> sentence.', '&amp; a second sentence.'],                                
          typeSpeed: 50,                                                                                  
        });                                                                                               
        return window.dash_clientside.no_update                                                           
    }                                                                                                     
    """,                                                                                                  
    Output('element', 'children'),                                                                        
    Input('element', 'children')                                                                          
)                                                                                                         
                                                                                                          
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Tnx! Just got it to work using an Interval and wanted to add an answer. However, your solution is much better without the need of an Interval. Next step is to see how to get this working in a Dash multiple pages application but that's my next challenge.